# OpenGL binding many textures while drawing the one mesh

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer, multitexturing

I would like to bind for example 80 textures on one mesh and put it in my VBO.
How can I achieve this?

I've read glActiveTexture is able to do that, however it allows max around 32 textures (GPU dependant).

My VBO code:

```
//Generating VBO
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*sizeof(Vector3d) + textureCoords.size()*sizeof(Vector2d), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices.size()*sizeof(Vector3d), vertices.data());
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*sizeof(Vector3d), textureCoords.size()*sizeof(Vector2d), textureCoords.data());

glGenBuffers(1, &IND);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IND);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size()*sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//Drawing VBO:
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_DOUBLE, 0, 0);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_DOUBLE, 0, (void*)(vertices.size()*sizeof(Vector3d)));

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IND);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Binding many (100s of) textures

I'm not sure of a way to bind that many separate textures at once. There are [bindless textures](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/specs/GL_NV_bindless_texture.txt) but I don't have much experience with that extension. You could also use an [array texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture) if many of your textures are the same size. But the standard approach to this problem is to use a **texture atlas**, where you pack lots of textures into the one, record where they're placed and adjust the texture coordinates to match.

Update: you could also use many texture arrays to store texture atlases (see comments and [@Ethan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30473338/1888983)).

---

### Applying multiple textures to a mesh

> How will I tell the VBO, what faces will have which texture?

I think a more immediate problem is is how you go about applying different textures (or materials) to the same mesh. There's a few things to consider...

1. The most common case for applying multiple textures is where each stores a different material attribute but they all use the same texture coordinates/"UVs". E.g. diffuse, normal, specular maps. I guess in the extreme case when you have 100s of different attributes is where you'd want an array texture.
2. If each texture needs to be mapped differently you'd have a separate per-vertex texture coordinate VBO for each texture. Then you'll have to decide how the textures interact or blend as they're applied.
3. You have completely separate materials/texture per face. Commonly there are only a few materials on the mesh. The way you render it is in separate batches, grouping by material. Bind the right texture, set the shader uniforms, draw triangle indices A to B.
4. If nearly every face has a different material. I guess this might be the case if you're drawing a tile based game with lots of different tiles.
   The problem here is the number of draw calls becomes a bottleneck,
   so you'll have to combine different materials into the same draw call.
   You could do this by storing the material on vertex attributes, such as adding a vertex colour VBO.
   Rather than just colour, you could store a per-vertex texture ID, and if you're using a texture atlas, the region in the atlas where your texture can be found.
   This starts to get inefficient because you'll have the same material data stored multiple times on each vertex of your triangles.
   To minimize the overhead, you could **store a material index per vertex**, which points to a material defined in a table somewhere (either in a small uniform array, or if you need more materials, another texture).
   Then add texture ID and atlas region to the material in the table.

   Hopefully this last point answers your question.

Comment: The textures are not all the same size and if I had to use texture atlas, it woul be really big texture.

Comment: @ProXicT you might need to create a number of texture atlases. Array textures can be used for that too.

Comment: Well, I have no idea how may I do that. How will I tell the VBO, what faces will have which texture?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I get it after reading yours and @Ethan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, if you have more than 32 textures for one mesh, you probably have a much bigger problem than binding issues. But if you insist on having that many textures, you have 2 options: Bindless or Texture array. However, there are drawbacks: Bindless will limit your hardware support. Texture array does require the textures to be of the same size and format. Personally I think Texture Array is a workable solution. You can try to resize your textures if possile, then group those with the same size & format into one array. Now, you have 32 arrays to work with, and that should be more than enough, e.g. one array for all albedo textures, one for all normal maps etc. Regarding resizing, consider scaling textures up to the largest size that you have, or maybe split into categories e.g. small, medium, large. Avoid arbitrary sizes.

Comment: I don't have that many textures, I want to implement textureloader which can be used with any mesh I'm loading. I think I get the idea, thanks :)

Comment: Do you need to render all of them at the same time or swap them at high frequency? If not, like a texture viewer, you can just get away with binding one at a time, then rebind when you need to draw a different texture.

Comment: Let's say I have a really big mesh with many textures assigned and the mesh I store in VBO. My current approach is to separate the mesh into certain amount of VBO's according to how many textures does the mesh have. So If I had for example 64 textures on one mesh, I would split it into 2 smaller meshes with 32 textures each and each mesh would have it's own VBO (2 in this case).

Comment: And according to NVIDIA, each VBO should have at least 4MB of data to provide best efficiency.

Comment: Can you point me to the document that says 4Mb is optimal VBO size? That's seems big for just one VBO. You don't need to split the mesh into 2 if you need texture switch. Simply use draw range and draw all the triangles with the first set of textures, then switch and draw the other set of triangles. Or redraw the entire mesh after switching texture. But that is rather inefficient.

Comment: I can't find the exact post, but here are some similar:
https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/163877-VBO-layout-of-attributes?p=1157916#post1157916
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/406182-vbo-size-questions/
To the VBO - that's what I want but how can I know where is starting new texture and where ends? How can I store that information into the VBO? I'm only storing there vertices, texcoords, normals and indices.